# Twitter Bootstrap and typeahead doesn't work correctly together

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

The following [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) code

```
  body
    div.container
      div.jumbotron
        h2 What do you want to find?
        form(action='/search', method='get')
          div.input-group
            input.typeahead.form-control(
              type='text',
              name='q',
              placeholder='Search'
            )
            div.input-group-btn
              button.btn.btn-default(type='submit')
                i.glyphicon.glyphicon-search
```

translates to this HTML (according to Chrome's F12):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>What do you want to find?</h2>
        <form action="/search" method="get">
            <div class="input-group"><span class="twitter-typeahead" style="position: relative; display: inline-block;"><input type="text" class="typeahead form-control tt-hint" readonly="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="-1" dir="ltr" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border-color: transparent; box-shadow: none; opacity: 1; background: none 0% 0% / auto repeat scroll padding-box border-box rgb(255, 255, 255);"><input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" class="typeahead form-control tt-input" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: transparent;"><pre aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; white-space: pre; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; word-spacing: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: auto; text-transform: none;"></pre><div class="tt-menu" style="position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; display: none;"><div class="tt-dataset tt-dataset-found-torrents"></div></div></span>
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you run it, you'll get the following result:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/kbjLmqeh/

As you can see, the input box doesn't have the correct size because of the some invalid interaction between [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/).

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently someone solve it, in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrtua/11/), by changing de CSS file.

This is the CSS:

```
.twitter-typeahead {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-query,
.twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #555555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-query,
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  border-color: #c09853;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-query,
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  border-color: #b94a48;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-query,
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  border-color: #468847;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-query:focus,
.twitter-typeahead .tt-hint:focus {
  border-color: #356635;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #7aba7b;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #7aba7b;
}
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-query:focus,
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint:focus {
  border-color: #a47e3c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #dbc59e;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #dbc59e;
}
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-query:focus,
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint:focus {
  border-color: #953b39;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #d59392;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #d59392;
}
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-query:focus,
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint:focus {
  border-color: #356635;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #7aba7b;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #7aba7b;
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  color: #a1a1a1;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.input-group .twitter-typeahead .tt-query {
  z-index: 2;
}
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-query,
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px !important;
}
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-query,
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0 !important;
}
.input-group .twitter-typeahead .tt-query,
.input-group .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-query,
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px !important;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-query,
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0 !important;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .tt-query,
.input-group.input-group-sm .tt-hint {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-query,
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px !important;
}
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-query,
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0 !important;
}
.input-group.input-group-lg .tt-query,
.input-group.input-group-lg .tt-hint {
  height: 45px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 160px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  *border-right-width: 2px;
  *border-bottom-width: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.tt-suggestion {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0081c2;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0077b3));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0077b3', GradientType=0);
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor a {
  color: #fff;
}
.tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't fix the "Search" button size -- http://i.imgur.com/I0p0Afr.png

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps: you can adjust the button yourself so it's inline with your input along with making the input 100% width.

Jade

```
body
  .container
    .jumbotron
      h2 What do you want to find?
      form(action='/search', method='get')
        .form-group
          .input-group
            input.typeahead.form-control(type='text', name='q', placeholder='Search')
            .input-group-btn
              button.btn.btn-default.btn-search(type='submit')
                i.glyphicon.glyphicon-search
```

See working example Snippet.

```js
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
}, {
  name: 'states',
  source: substringMatcher(states)
});
```

```css
/*Typeahead 100% Width*/

.twitter-typeahead {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
/*Style Typeahead*/

.typeahead:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0097cf;
}
.tt-query {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.tt-hint {
  color: #999;
}
.tt-menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 12px 0;
  padding: 8px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.tt-suggestion {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.tt-suggestion:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;
}
.tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}
/**Adjust the Button**/

.input-group .input-group-btn .btn-search {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
/**Adjust Jumbotron below 768px**/

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .jumbotron {
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h2>What do you want to find?</h2>
      <form action="/search" method="get">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" class="typeahead form-control" />
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-search"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It sounds strange but the same code doesn't work for me -- the "Search" button has the wrong size (it's smaller than the input box) -- http://i.imgur.com/4rUPw8I.png. What can be the reason? My code -- http://pastie.org/10564403

Comment: That's definitely odd. My first thought is if you have any CSS rules that may be causing it to behave this way.